# SAPUI5 get username/userid from OData request

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am currently focussing a problem which I thought it would be easy to solve. but I didnt. There are controls which allow us to show the username or logged in user, such as the lovely **shell-headitems**:

```js
var oShell = new sap.ui.ux3.Shell("myShell", {
    headerItems: [
                new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
                text: oController.getUserName() }),
                 ],
});
```

It looks like this:

[image: Header Item top right (currently a string)]

In here we define headerItems, which are in my opinion foreseen to show a username / or the currently logged in user. but how can I receive it? my idea is to get it from the odata request, which was made earlier. It requires me to enter username and password -> thus I want to **read this username** in my **controller-method**, but how?

```js
getUserName : function() {
        // return navigator.userAgent;
        var model = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
        return model.getProperty('sUser'); // doesnt work :(
},
```

I also tried to get it from `navigator.userAgent()` but this information does not belong to the user.
Anybody knows how to receive it?

And yes: I searched in google and found some threads discussing about users/login but none of these threads solved my issue. Otherwise I thought about transferring sy-uname from SAP to the frontend, but how could you send a single Text? I don't want to build a complete service for this single transaction.

If you do not provide `sUser` and `sPassword` during `oData-Model-Initialization` it will be empty during runtime. You cannot access it from the model, though I realized an own service for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The username is in the `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataMetadata` of ODataModel.

```js
var getUserName = function() {
    var model = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
    var sUser = model.oMetadata.sUser;
    // Display user logic here.
};

oModel.attachMetadataLoaded(null,getUserName);
```

**Update answer for comment question from zyrex:**

```
var user = new sap.ui.commons.TextView();

var getUserNameCallBack = function(userName) {
    user.setText(userName);
}

oController.getUserName(getUserNameCallBack);
```

Controller method:

```
getUserName: function(callback) {
    var userName = '';

    $.getJSON(sServiceUrl).done(function(data) {
        userName = data.d.Name;
        callback(userName);

    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Allen, console says: "oMetadata is undefined or null". How to initialize it? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using ODataModel?

Comment: yes:  onInit : function() {

  var sServiceUrl = 'xxx',
  var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, true);
  sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

 },

Comment: it seems you did not user var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, true, sUser?, sPassword?), how do you handle your user log on?

Comment: its asking for a user when I open my page (thats the way I prefer, I dont want to enter user/password in the code)

Comment: my question is that how the authentication is done, since you don not call ODataModel initialization with user and password, then i suppose you handle the authentication by your own code, it is not hard for you to get the user name after successful log on.

Comment: its also made by standard, I did not realize any authentication function, it works the same then passing it to the model directly. I just added user and password to my code and still it says "oMetadata is undefined" :(

Comment: you need to attachMetadataLoaded to the ODataModel. See the updated answer.

Comment: currently I got var user = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({       text : oController.getUserName(), }); + the method: getUserName : function() { var userName = ''; $.getJSON(sServiceUrl)      .done(function(data){ userName = data.d.Name; console.log(userName); } ); return userName; } but i dont get the value, tried to read millions of posts but my name is not returned (though in console.log the name is correct) ... can you help me?

Comment: hi, you need to do it by a callback function as the JSON request is async. Please see my updated answer.